# Using awk to print data from a specific sequence of lines as data arranged as a row

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file organized like this:

```
a b c d 
x1 
x2
x3
e f g h 
x4 
x5 
x6
```

and so on. I would like to use awk to write another file as follows:

```
 x1 x2 x3  
 x4 x5 x6
```

and so on. I am struggling since I'm still beginning to learn awk and sed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Kindly do add your tried code as your efforts in your question, thank you.

Comment: Check if the first character is `'x'` (e.g. `/^x/`) If it is, write the field include a space conditionally if not the first write for that line (e.g. keep a counter), e.g. `{printf "%s%s",(n++)?" ":"",$1; next}`, skip to next record. If the field doesn't begin with `/^x/` check if the counter is set and write a newline, reset the counter zero, e.g. `n {print ""; n=0}` Then use the `END` rule to write the final newline with `print ""`. See if you can get that working. 2 rules total. (hint, checking just `n` is equivalent to checking `n != 0`)

Comment: Always consult [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) Remember each rule consists of an optional condition (pattern) and then the rule enclosed in `{...}` so, `/^x/ {...}` would be 1 rule. Awk processes each line of input by applying the rules you write to each line -- in the order you write them.

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
a b c d 
x1 
x2
x3
e f g h 
x4 
x5 
x6
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "}NR==1{next}NF==1{print $1}NF>1{printf "\n"}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
x1 x2 x3 
x4 x5 x6
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` to use space as output row separator (`ORS`), then for 1st row to go `next` row (skipping first row), if row has 1 field I do `print` 1st record (`$1`) which gets trailing space rather than newline, as I set `ORS` to space. If there is more than one field I just `printf` newline. Observe that `printf` does not add trailing space as opposed to `print`. If you want to know more about `ORS` or `NR` or `NF` then read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*